# Do not print stack trace on Postfix's mail delivery failure notification

Tags: postfix-mta

When our service fails to deliver an email, the rejection notification returned to the sender contains the stack trace of the code that failed. Is there a way to send the delivery notification, without the attached errors?

We have a postfix server that handles incoming emails in a catchall python script. That script uploads the email to one of our services and throws an exception in case it failed.

This is the template we are using

```
failure_template = <<EOF
Charset: us-ascii
From: MAILER-DAEMON (Mail Delivery System)
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
Postmaster-Subject: Postmaster Copy: Undelivered Mail

This is the mail system at host $myhostname.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to <postmaster>

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system
EOF
```

Expected result would be just the template notification, without the strack trace of the catch-all script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mail server simply includes in the bounce whatever your Python program displays on its standard error. Maybe call the script via a wrapper which saves the standard error to a sane place (or even discards it, if you are sure it never contains anything useful).

```
#!/bin/sh
python3 /path/to/deliver.py 2>>/var/log/deliver.log
```

Your mail server obviously needs to have write access to the log, and you'll probably want to set up periodic log rotation for the file.

Probably a better overall approach is for the Python program to not crash.